# Update RowKey or PartitionKey in Azure Table Storage

Tags: c#, azure, http-status-code-404, azure-table-storage

Can i update RowKey or PartitionKey properties of entity in Azure Table Storage?

I thought yes or maybe just PartitionKey but now i am trying to do that(try to change RowKey or PartitionKey) and get error:

```
The remote server returned an error: (404) Not Found.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current 
             web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about 
             the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error:
                  (404) Not Found.

Source Error:

Line 143:
Line 144:                var updateOperation = TableOperation.Replace(entity);
Line 145:                _table.Execute(updateOperation);
Line 146:            }
Line 147:        }
```

### My Code to update entity(short version):

```
var query = new TableQuery<CalculatorAccessTokenEntity>()
                .Where(TableQuery.GenerateFilterCondition("AccessUrl", 
                                                           QueryComparisons.Equal, url));

var newToken = GetUniqueKey(5);//get some random string of length 5
entity.PartitionKey = newToken;

// Try to use Merge here also but unsuccessful
var updateOperation = TableOperation.Replace(entity);    _table.Execute(updateOperation);
```

Answer (score 38, accepted):

No, you can't update an entity's `PartitionKey` or `RowKey`. What you would need to do is perform 2 operations: first delete the entity with existing PartitionKey/RowKey and then insert new entity with new PartitionKey/RowKey.

Comment: yes, you are wright, as it's like unique key for entity.

Comment: one more question : can i delete and insert operation "union" to execute this code `_table.Execute(operation)`only once?

Comment: No, they will have to be two separate operations. However if your PartitionKey is not changing, you can make use of Entity Batch Transactions. That way you're ensuring that either both operation succeed or fail.